# Glass box in American Crime Story

Tags: american-crime-story, the-people-v-o-j-simpson

I made this screen cap while watching "American Crime Story"...

[image]

Behind the District Attorney, there appears to be an official sitting in a glass box, but the defendant appears elsewhere (on the far right to the left of John Travolta). So this isn't to protect the defendant from gunfire.

What, then, is the purpose of this glass box?

Comment: He looks like another guard. Maybe he's behind bulletproof glass so he'll be safe if someone pulls a gun on the other officers. That will give him time to react during an incident.

Comment: It's not a box: it's open in the front. But this has got nothing to do with the show, this is simply the show recreating the actual court room: http://imgur.com/D7t7hDm .